# Excel VBA - Post with empty cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a Macro that takes text entered into a textbox and posts it to the next empty row. This simulates a running list. The problem is that if the textbox is left blank, the next time the user clicks the post button the text is entered in the last empty cell which doesn't line up with the row number for the other columns.

How do I chnage the code so that if the textbox is left blank, we can insert text to keep the row number aligned with other text that was entered.

```
Private Sub Post_Click()

bFree = Range("B8:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("B" & bFree).Value2 = cell.value
dFree = Range("D8:D" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("D" & dFree).Value2 = Amount.value
eFree = Range("E8:E" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("E" & eFree).Value2 = Vendor.value

End Sub
```

In the picture below you can see that when no date was entered during for a post after January the next date is one row behind. The current code takes the next empty row only when text is entered, so I think I need to insert text when text boxes are empty to keep the row number.

[image]

Comment: In addition to the excellent bandaid proposed below, you could have the 'Post' code check if any of the relevant cells are blank before creating a new record.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the next blank for each column. Don't do that. Only use one column to decide what the next row is. I recommend using an ID column, like the one you call `No.` because this is how a database table works. In fact, what you are doing would just happen automatically if you were using MS Access instead of Excel.

As your `No.` Column is currently blank we are forced to use a column where we know it won't be empty. I will use `D` in my example.

```
Private Sub Post_Click()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B" & lastRow).Value2 = cell.value
        .Range("D" & lastRow).Value2 = Amount.value
        .Range("E" & lastRow).Value2 = Vendor.value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Failing having a valid `No.` column, rather than designate one at random I'd get the max of .end(xlup).row of each row and use that.

Comment: @HackSlash we would need the values to be posted each time the button is clicked and have the first entry start in row 8. Also I would like to have the `No.` column working but I couldn't find am increment solution online using the post function. Please share if you have one!

Comment: Yes. Use MS Access. You can pound a nail with a screwdriver but I recommend using a hammer. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/access